# Stackdriver vs Prometheus - what is the main differences?

Tags: kubernetes, google-stackdriver, prometheus

Moving from on-premise monlotic architechture style to microservices running in GCP on Kubernetes Cluster.
I would like to understand Stackdriver compared to Prometheus. I can not get what the difference is. What can Stackdriver do what Prometheus can not? And vise versa?

Comment: You may want to check [this link](https://stackshare.io/stackups/loggly-vs-prometheus-vs-stackdriver)

Answer (score 1):

https://stackshare.io/stackups/prometheus-vs-stackdriver

Heads up: you're comparing apples to oranges.